# Codeigniter Check if function in model exists from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hope this is just something quick, but I can't find something that works.

I want to check if a function exists in a model from a controller in CodeIgniter, and if it does, it should run the function.

I have tried the following:

```
$comp_model = 'model_comp_'.$comp_code;
$this->load->model('comp/'.$comp_model);

if (function_exists($this->$comp_model->join_comp))
...
```

and

```
if (method_exists($this, $comp_model->join_comp()))
...
```

even just calling the function in the if statement

```
if ($this->$comp_model->join_comp())
...
```

Please help!

Comment: No use of Your Question. This no longer proceed any answer

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: whats is the purpose of checking that??

Comment: [rtfm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: I need to automatically write something in a database, but only if that function exists...To Explain, we are a dance competition organization, and for some of our competitions you need to apply for memberships and others you are automatically approve, and if that function exists, you are automatically approved

Comment: @Meneer Venus, I tried that as stated above, but it give an error, and does not say what the error is, is it supposed to work like i stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just implement the method in all models? I think you should create a parent with an protected method called `join_comp()` and make all your models derive from that parent. You could just add the 'automatic approval' code to the specified model.

Comment: I scratched the idea, decided its easier to make it so that when the school does the first entry, it will be added to the database, and when the last entry is removed, the school is removed as well, just makes a bit more sense to me, but thanx for the help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
$modelName = 'some_model';
$pageModelPath = APPPATH . 'models' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $modelName . '.php';
if( file_exists( $pageModelPath ) ){
    require $pageModelPath;
    $model = new $modelName;

    if( method_exists($model, 'myFunction') ){
        $model->myFunction();
    }
}
```